# Permanent "alien" alert issue

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

One of my squad members seems to be permanently stuck with an alien-in-view alert. As far as I can tell, he always has one more alert than is relevant (he always sees one more alien than there actually are within his line of sight).

One the one hand, this is handy, since he's an assault class and I'm guessing gets bonuses for this, but at the same time, it's very annoying to keep hearing the "I saw an alien" audio alert, when no alien is anywhere within his sights.

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a work-around? I've tried reloading the game from save, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you mean that he does the "shout" that soldiers do the first time an alien appears on screen? Or does the alien icon show when it really shouldn't?

Comment: Known bug, I think. It's happened to me more times than I can be bothered to remember. *Seems* to be caused by an alien being killed in an overwatch shot triggered by their free run-into-cover move when they're first sighted, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: @Sandokan he does both of those. Each turn, he does the shout, and shows the icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug that many people have reported seeing. I myself have even experienced that multiple times... There is really nothing you can do about it other than try to ignore it until a patch fixes it, I'm afraid.

Comment: well you could try and figure out the circumstances under which this happened, e.g. as [Shadur claims](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120099/permanent-alien-alert-issue#comment161919_120099) was this due to an overwatch shot after alien discovery?